# How to refresh the page in Mechanize?

Tags: python, mechanize

I'm using Mechanize in Python to submit a form and view some info. The URL goes to some standard URL for the request, without the request parameters in it. Something like: xyzdomain.com/request

In the browser, it normal shows a loading icon, then displays the data. There is no change in the top of the page (header) so the full page is never reloaded, but the URL does change from /index to /request.

About 1/3 of the time, I get a httplib.IncompleteRead exception and I checked the partial HTML of the response and the page is saying "If it takes longer than 25 seconds, refresh the page."

So if I grabbed the current URL of the Mechanize Browser and used open() on it, would that have the same affect as using refresh (if Mechanize had refresh).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this might help

```
br.set_handle_refresh(mechanize._http.HTTPRefreshProcessor(), max_time=1)
```

For more: [Meta Refresh](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/tutor/2011-August/084951.html)